# API jar without parent pom dependency

Tags: java, maven

We have the following structure:

```
myRootFolder
- pom.xml (pom1 - parent pom defining modules)
-core-app/
  - pom.xml
-core-libs/
  - pom.xml (pom2 - defining modules and having pom1 as parent pom)
  - common-api/
    - pom.xml (pom3 - the api with pom2 as parent pom)
  - other-lib/
    - pom.xml
```

Within our common-api we have protobuf messages defined, and also helper classes and types we define and want others to use.

When we provide the common-api.jar to a customer they also need the two parent poms (pom2 and pom1) in order to re-deploy them on their own maven server.

A way to provide them the poms we could make our maven repository public, at least the parts needed, but unfortunately that's not an option at the moment.

Is there a way to automatically create the common-api.jar where the containing pom does not contain the dependency to the parent(s) but still is working properly? (the versions defined within the parent pom are written into the pom, replaced by the version defined in the parent pom (pom1), and not for instance `${log4j.version}`) ?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is way but not the standard way to handle maven builds. 
You may use
  `mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=xxx.xml`
 this generates the effective POM as an XML for the current build, with the active profiles factored in.
Effective POM is composed of Super POM + Application POM(s) + settings.xml contents + plugins bound to the lifecycle by default based on the packaging type chosen (thus, based on one element in the Application POM).

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, that goes into the right direction, although it's too much that's getting composed into the final pom...